# Restlet Route Same API with Different HTTP Methods

Tags: java, restlet

I have 2 APIs as follows:

```
GET [baseURL]/user/{userID}
DELETE [baseURL]/user/{userID}
```

How can I route them correctly based on HTTP method in restlet ?

Here is my code that is not working -

For GET-

```
Router rootRouter = new Router(getContext());
rootRouter.attach("/user/{userID}", GetUserRest.class);
rootRouter.setDefaultMatchingMode(Template.MODE_STARTS_WITH);
rootRouter.setRoutingMode(Router.MODE_LAST_MATCH);
```

For DELETE-

```
Router rootRouter = new Router(getContext());
rootRouter.attach("/user/{userID}", CancelUserRest.class);
rootRouter.setDefaultMatchingMode(Template.MODE_STARTS_WITH);
rootRouter.setRoutingMode(Router.MODE_LAST_MATCH);
```

Since both are attached with the same rootRouter and have same URL so restlet didn't know which class to call if its GET or DELETE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution-

Use same routing and same class for both. Then in class put annotation for GET and POST.

```
public class GetUserRest extends ServerResource{
    @Get @Delete
    public String getUser() throws ResourceException {
      if(getMethod().getName().equals("DELETE")) {
            return "delete method";
        } else if(getMethod().getName().equals("GET")) {
            return "get method";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to keep the implementation of GET and DELETE in separate classes, but attach them to same URL-pattern in `Router`. I have seen your answer, but do think about this solution as well, in case someone likes another approach:

I know 1 way to solve this, make 3 classes: `User`, `UserGet` and `UserDel`.

```
rootRouter.attach("/user/{userID}", User.class);
```

User.java

```
public class User
{   @Get
    public Object getImpl()
    {   UserGet userGet = new UserGet();
        // init userGet
        return userGet.createResponse();
    }
    @Delete
    public Object delImpl()
    {   UserDel userDel = new UserDel();
        // init userDel
        return userDel.createResponse();
    }
}
```

I hope this solution also works fine.